# Grant SP group manage permissions, but not be able to grant Full control

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-permissions

I'd like to have a specific SharePoint group with the ability to manage permissions on a site, but **only** be able to grant edit and read. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no option to only be able to grant edit and read permission.

Once uses have permissions to grant permission, all permission levels can be grant.